# NodeJS Crypto RS-SHA256 and JWT Bearer

Tags: node.js, cryptography, oauth-2.0, jwt

In implementing an oauth2 stack utilizing passport and oauth2orize, in this case the issue is specifically in utilizing the oauth2orize jwt bearer. The oauth2orize jwt bearer is great in getting everything going, however it has the RSA SHA pieces marked as to do.

In attempting to put in the pieces for the RSA SHA encryption handling, I cannot get the signature to verify as verifier.verify always seems to return false. If anyone has cleared this hurdle, a little help would be super.

What I've done:
Created the private / public keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024
//extract public key
openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

now the data to sign:

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}{"iss": "myclient"}
```

I've tried multiple ways as to how to sign this, too many to list here, but my understanding of the correct signature is to sign the bas64 encoding of these items, so i ran base64 on  {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"} and base64 on {"iss": "myclient"} then ran base64 on those encodings. So the result is:
`eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
eyJpc3MiOiAibXljbGllbnQifQ`
then encode:

```
{eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9}.{eyJpc3MiOiAibXljbGllbnQifQ}
```

which gives me:
`e2V5SmhiR2NpT2lKU1V6STFOaUlzSW5SNWNDSTZJa3BYVkNKOX0ue2V5SnBjM01pT2lBaWJYbGpiR2xsYm5RaWZRfQ`

At this point I sign the above base64 by doing:

```
openssl sha -sha256 -sign priv.pem < signThis > signedData
```

Then I run base64 on that to get the data to pass into the signature part of the assertion.
I then pass in the object:

```
{
"grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
"assertion":  "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiAibXljbGllbnQifQ.signedData"
}
```

now in the code base I have:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
   , fs = require('fs')
   , pub = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/pub.pem')
   , verifier = crypto.createVerify("RSA-SHA256");

verifier.update(JSON.stringify(data));

var result = verifier.verify(pub, signature, 'base64');
console.log('vf: ', result);
```

however, result is always false.

I do properly receive the data, the signature variable in the code is a match for what I'm passing in, I just always receive false and have exhausted all options I can think of on how to tweak this to get verifier.verify to return true. Thank you for the time and help!

Comment: Could you point us to the specifications for what you are trying to compute? I don't see many documents mentioning RSA/SHA-1 for OAuth 2.0 (but that may be my ignorance of the standard). Encoding to base 64 *before* signature generation seems not right to me. Normally you use *character encoding* before signature generation over text, and base 64 to turn the generated signature to text if required by the protocol.

Comment: As you don't seem to answer, can we flag this post as abandoned?

Comment: I apologize for the delay, I've been on out for the holidays.Thank you for the response! I have tried encoding both before and after the base64, to no avail. I also am a bit ignorant of the standard, and am doing my best to try and decipher what I'm doing wrong here. I am basing the rsa/sha256 based on the sample code in the oauth2orize jwt sample and also on the google oauth2 server to server documentation. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: I too am working on something very similar. I have been trying to use jwt-simple and it does seem to simplify the process: [jwt-simple](https://github.com/hokaccha/node-jwt-simple). I will let you know if I find the solution completely.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but this will successfully create a JWT in a google api fashion using jwt-simple (which uses crypto and such):

```
var fs       = require('fs')
  , jwt      = require('jwt-simple')
  , keypath  = '/path/to/your.pem'
  , secret   = fs.readFileSync( keypath, { encoding: 'ascii' })
  , now      = Date.now()
  , payload  = {
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/<service>',
        iss  : '<iss_id>@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        aud  : 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        iat  : now,
        exp  : now+3600
    }
  , token    = jwt.encode( payload, secret, 'RS256' )
  , decoded  = jwt.decode( token, secret, 'RS256' );

console.log( token );
console.log( decoded );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code sample is completely unsecure. If you look at the latest JWT code, it doesn't event use the secret on your decode call.

https://github.com/hokaccha/node-jwt-simple/blob/master/lib/jwt.js

It basically just decodes the second segment and returns it which means anyone could have changed the value and its not verified.